# How to create a unique id for each insert in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to have a unique ID for each INSERT. All rows for each INSERT must have the same ID, but different to the other IDs in the table. Is any standard way to do that in ORACLE?

Comment: Shouldnt it be all rows for each INSET must have unique ID?

Comment: I have a hard time understanding "all rows of each INSERT". How exactly are you writing that INSERT statement? `insert .. select?` something else? If every new row should get a new ID, then just define an `identity` column

Comment: Why can't you use [SYS_GUID](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions202.htm#SQLRF06120) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use sequence in Oracle :

```
CREATE SEQUENCE my_sq START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;
```

Then when you want to insert, use my_seq.NEXTVAL in the place of your "by insert id"

More info about [SEQUENCE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6015.htm#SQLRF01314)